# .htaccess domain directory wildcard redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I currently have 2 domains domain1.com and domain2.com. I need to [wildcard] 301 redirect all pages in /reviews/ from domain1.com to domain2.com, while the remaining pages remain accessible on domain1.com

> domain1.com/reviews/city/New-York/ -> domain2.com/reviews/city/New-York/
>   domain1.com/reviews/city/Seattle/ -> domain2.com/reviews/city/Seattle/

and so on, and so forth.

This is what I have now in domain1.com's htaccess, but it's not working for whatever reason:

```
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)$ http://domain2.com/reviews/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following rule above your `RewriteEngine on` directive:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /reviews/(.*) http://domain2.com/reviews/$1
```

This must be before any Rewrites and must be in the htaccess file in the root folder of domain 1.